# Which chain for developing a BTC based app?

Tags: bitcoin-core, development, testnet, regtest, signet

There appear to be four chains you can use with bitcoin-cli. Main, test, signet, and regtest.

Main is off the list obviously but I'm not sure which other chain I should be using. I'll need to be able to send and receive test transactions and play around with using wallets at the same time.

I'm using bitcoin core 25 on macOS.